# Regex: How to validate that a path does not contain //

Tags: php, javascript, regex, path

I need help to create a regex (for JavaScript .match and PHP preg_match) that validates a unix type absolute path to a file (with international characters such as åäöøæð and so on) so that:

1. /path/to/someWhere is valid
2. /path/tø/sömewhere is valid
3. /path/to//somewhere is **invalid**
4. path/to/somewhere is **invalid**
5. /path/to/somewhere/ is **invalid**

The regex needs to handle paths regardless of their depth (/path/to or /path/to/somewhere or /path/to/somewhere/else)

I have a regexp that marks 1 to 3 as valid /^\/.+[^\/]$/ , the problem is to make this regex not to mark 3 as valid as it contains // without any other character in between.

Comment: I love regex posts like this, to an outsider we all look like spambots or something.

Comment: Unix/Linux pathnames actually work just fine if they end in a slash or have double-slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Solution for PHP:

```
    $lines =  array(
        "/path/to/someWhere",
        "/path/tø/sömewhere",
        "/path/to//somewhere",
        "path/to/somewhere",
        "/path/to/somewhere/",
    );

    foreach($lines as $line){
        var_dump(preg_match('#^(/[^/]+)+$#',$line)); // dumps int(1) int(1) int(0) int(0) int(0) 
    }
```

Comment: That pattern does not match "/", a single slash, which is a valid pathname.

Comment: ^(/[^/]+)+$ was exactly what I was looking for, so simple when you see it. I forgot to say that I did not want to validate only / as this root level is kind of a directory. This regexp is perfect for my needs. Thanks

Comment: np, repetition rules, repetition rules

Answer (score 4):

Regex isn't really needed here. As far as I can see, there are three things you want to ensure:

1. The string starts with `/`
2. The string doesn't end with `/`, unless the whole string *is* `/`
3. The string doesn't contain any instances of `//`

All three of the above can be done with string functions.

In PHP:

```
if ($string != '/' && ($string[0] != '/' || $string[strlen($string)-1] == '/' || strpos($string, '//') > -1))
{
  // string is invalid
}
```

In Javascript:

```
if (string != '/' && (string.charAt(0) != '/' || string.charAt(string.length - 1) == '/' || string.indexOf('//') > -1))
{
  // string is invalid
}
```

Resources:

- PHP's [strpos](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function
- Javascript's [String.charAt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp) and [String.indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) functions

Comment: The pathname consisting of a single slash **is** a valid pathname.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
^(:?\/$|(:?\/[^/]+)+$)
```

That says to accept any string that's either *just* a /, or any string formed from a sequence of one or more repetitions of a / followed by one or more non-/ characters.

This uses all greedy quantifiers so it should be fast; also, for performance, the ^ anchor is factored out.

That's a Javascript regex. I'm not a PHP programmer so the main thing I don't know is whether the non-capturing group syntax works in PHP. Also, I'm not sure how you'd handle "quoting" the slash characters.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^/[^/]?$|^/[^/]([^/]|/[^/])*?[^/]$
```

It allows any character except `/`, **or** a `/` *followed by* any character except `/`. It also makes sure that the last character isn’t a `/`, and that the second character isn’t one either.

Finally, this uses `/` without escaping. To use it in PHP, don’t use `/` as the regex delimiter – this just makes the regular expression hard to read. Use any other character, e.g. `;` to delimit the expression instead:

```
;^/[^/]?$|^/[^/]([^/]|/[^/])*?[^/]$;
```

**EDIT**: Added special handing for the root path, `"/"`, and paths that consist of a single letter directory.

Comment: This doesn't match "/", a single slash, which is the pathname for the root directory.  Also, non-greedy quantifiers can cause performance problems.

Comment: @Pointy: it’s the *greedy* quantifiers that may cause performance problems. But good call about the root path.

Comment: Well it depends on the regex. Using a greedy quantifier can significantly reduce backtracking. [See this excellent blog post.](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance)

Comment: @Pointy: True but in this case there are no nested quantifiers so catastrophic backtracking cannot happen, and in this case it actually saves us one backtracking because the last character won’t be consumed and then spit out again.

Comment: I'm no expert. One of these days I need to try out Regex Buddy :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the path matches `^[^\/]|\/\/|.\/$`, it is invalid. Otherwise it is valid.

Comment: A pathname consisting of a single slash is a valid pathname.

Answer (score 0):

it's not regex, but works just as well.

```
str_replace('//', '/', $file)
```

Comment: This doesn't do any of the 3 checks required, it only replaces on one condition.

Comment: I'm only suggesting to use your normal RegEx with str_replace instead of going nuts with the RegEx and making a suboptimal token disaster.  Given the RegEx in the OP, yes it does do the required.